# Would a non-Muslim sin if he proclaimed himself a Muslim for the sake of solidarity?

Tags: non-muslim, sin

For those interested, I'll also be asking this question on [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55372/would-a-non-christian-sin-if-here-to-proclaim-himself-a-christian-for-the-sake-o) and [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/would-a-non-jew-sin-if-here-to-proclaim-himself-a-jew-for-the-sake-of-solidarity) (with respect to those religions).

In recent rallies, protesting what is perceived as bigoted policies by president Donald Trump, several individuals who are not in fact Muslim and do not subscribe to the Islamic faith have claimed they are Muslim in a show of solidarity with the Muslim world.

[image: We are all Muslim]

([Michael Moore](http://michaelmoore.com/WeAreAllMuslim/))

Would a non-Muslim sin if he proclaimed himself a Muslim for the sake of solidarity?

While I generally understand that not subscribing to the faith in general is sinful, I'm curious about the act of proclaiming that you are an adherent when that is not true (I'm asking in particular about the sin of falsely claiming adherence to the faith, this should be understood as being a different or greater magnitude sin than simply violating any general rules about lying or telling falsehoods).

Comment: If they are clearly not Muslim by their actions and what they do and say that they are Muslims then it is hypocrisy (nifaq)

Comment: The key words here is 'for the sake of solidarity'; the gesture by Michael Moore for example is purely political gesture and not a religious gesture affirming faith and he takes that to be understood by his audience; in this sense its neither sinful or not.

Answer (score 4):

There are always two sides of the medal: If the intention is good I'd say it can be considered as a good deed, so it isn't sinful. But from an other perspective (pure theologically) it could be considered as hypocrisy. Again on the other hand showing solidarity and having a clear position is anything but hypocrisy! This of course is my analysis from the perspective of Islam.

But the Quran and sunnah seem to reflect that good deeds of a disbeliever (as long as he doesn't convert) won't help him on judgement day:

> **From The Quran:**
>
> - ... And whoever of you reverts from his religion [to disbelief] and dies while he is a disbeliever - for those, their deeds have become worthless in this world and the Hereafter, and those are the companions of the Fire, they will abide therein eternally. ([2:217](http://legacy.quran.com/2/217))
> - ...  And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers. ([5:5](http://legacy.quran.com/5/5))
> - And We have already sent [messengers] to nations before you, [O Muhammad]; then We seized them with poverty and hardship that perhaps they might humble themselves [to Us]. ([6:42](http://legacy.quran.com/6/42))
>   Then why, when Our punishment came to them, did they not humble themselves? But their hearts became hardened, and Satan made attractive to them that which they were doing. ([6:43](http://legacy.quran.com/6/43))
> - And what prevents their expenditures from being accepted from them but that they have disbelieved in Allah and in His Messenger and that they come not to prayer except while they are lazy and that they do not spend except while they are unwilling. ([9:54](http://legacy.quran.com/9/54))
> - And it was already revealed to you and to those before you that if you should associate [anything] with Allah , your work would surely become worthless, and you would surely be among the losers." ([39:65](http://legacy.quran.com/39/65))
>
> **From the sunnah:**
>
> - I said: Messenger of Allah, the son of Jud'an established ties of relationship, fed the poor. Would that be of any avail to him? He said: It would be of no avail to him as he did not ever say: O my Lord, pardon my sins on the Day of Resurrection. (sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:214))
> - When a non-believer does good he is made to taste Its reward in this world. And so far as the believer is concerned, Allah stores (the reward) of his virtues for the Hereafter and provides him sustenance in accordance with his obedience to Him. (sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/52/44))
> - "Whoever says, 'None has the right to be worshipped but Allah', faces our Qibla during the prayers, prays like us and eats our slaughtered animal, then he is a Muslim, and has got the same rights and obligations as other Muslims have." (sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/8/45))

At the end it is up to Allah not to us to judge!
Allah says:

> So whoever does an atom's weight of good will see it, ([99:7](http://legacy.quran.com/99/7))
> And whoever does an atom's weight of evil will see it. ([99:8](http://legacy.quran.com/99/8))

Note that the whole surah addresses the people -in general- not explicitly the Muslims! So one could conclude "whoever" here as referring to both Muslims and non-Muslims. And this surah is Madani or Makki according to some sources ([see wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az-Zalzala). If it is Makki one could conclude that it was abrogated by the verses quoted above.

Answer (score 1):

> Would a non-Muslim sin if he proclaimed himself a Muslim for the sake of solidarity?

Regardless of the issue of solidarity, do non-Muslim sin when they eat pork, worship before statues, or fail to perform the five pillars of faith?
From a Muslim perspective, non-Muslims are by definition living in a continual state of sin.
This specific act would be no different.

But should this incident be considered blasphemous, disrespectful, or offensive?

When Michael Moore and others hold up those signs, they really don't mean it literally, and don't expect anyone else to take it literally.
They aren't making a false claim in order to hurt anyone or to take personal advantage of it (e.g. to visit holy sites).

What they are saying to the offenders is "*When you attack Islam, you also attack me. When you offend Muslims for their beliefs, you also offend me for my beliefs.*".
What they are saying to Muslims is "*I recognize the injustice you have received. I share your pain.*".

The sign itself might be too short and simple, but its intended message is far from being a sin.

Comment: it would be more complete if you've included evidences from the quran and sunnah.

Answer (score 0):

How can helping an oppressed people, even in such a way a showing solidarity, ever be considered a sin? Moroever I don't think it is their intention to actually become Muslim or even pretend to be Muslim, it is just a way of showing their support.

So I don't think it is a sin, but Allah is the Judge and He Knows best.